# select a mix of multiple entries

Tags: mysql, autocomplete

I have a table with two columns:

```
Name | Type
```

Now I am querying this table from an autocomplete HTML form and I would like to get a result similar to this pseudo query.

```
SELECT 10 Closest_Names FOR EACH TYPE WHERE Names LIKE INPUT
```

Any idea how the real query would look like?

Comment: What do you mean by "closest names"? I don't think you can query MySQL directly for that. Maybe you're looking for the levenshtein function : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757251/php-using-levenshtein-distance-to-match-words

Comment: This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140589/mysql-query-select-top-3-rows-from-table-for-each-category

Comment: Thanks for the levenshtein hint. I bet it's useful, but the delay generated might be too long for a autocomplete query. Thanks :)

Comment: I think mysql's [FULL TEXT support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) will do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

i have a experience in autocomplete that value comes from database
you are asking for QUERY right? here's my example, i hope it will help

```
SELECT name,type FROM <table> WHERE name like '%input%' LIMIT 10
```